# Cómo realizar una requisición de un Json del Json-server ( Fake ResT API ) usando Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Buen día!

Tengo un Json (db.json) en el Json server (Fake Rest API ) pero necesito realizar post,get,put usando jquery/javascript.
Me podrian orientar a respecto?
Desde ya muchas gracias!

```
function SalvarPessoa(event) {  
    alert( "Salvar" );

    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/objPessoa';
    var data = {"nome" : $('#inputNome').val(), "documento" : $('#inputDocumento').val(), "telefone"   : $('#inputTelefone').val()};

    $.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
        return jQuery.ajax({
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': url,
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'data': JSON.stringify(data),
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success': callback
        });
    };
```

Observación: tengo estoy llenando 3 campos de un formulario en html5. Tengo un Json de mi Api rest fake ( Json server, instaladco localmente). Leí algo sobre sobre Api fetch, pero solo me crea el ID por la consola del navegador. Los demás campos no los trae por consola

Comment: Hola, agrega mas información y el código que tienes para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: @the-breaker tengo estoy llenando 3 campos de un formulario en html5.
Tengo un Json de mi Api rest fake ( Json server, instaladco localmente).
Leí algo sobre sobre Api fetch, pero solo me crea el ID por la consola del navegador.
Los demás campos no los trae por consola.